# MHDD не видит хард Samsung

Tags: hdd, dos

Взял б\у HDD Samsung IDE на 120 Gb. Естественно решил проверить MHDD. Но программа его не видит. БИОС, линукс, виндовс его определяют, и он доступен для чтения\записи. Но из-по ДОСа ни в какую. Если на его "место" подключить старый WD, то он определяется MHDD без проблем. Но этот Самсунг не хочет. Читал, что в БИОСе можно попробовать включить режим LBA, но такого выбора нет (именно для этого диска). Есть только Auto и Large. На этом харде стоит перемычка на Master, на WD перемычек нет вообще.

На днях хотел проверить хард своего знакомого, так вот он тоже не был определен.

Читал, что это именно из за Самсунга, с этим производителем нередко встречаются подобные проблемы.

Что можно попробовать ещё?

Comment: Что-то не очень похоже на онтопик.

Comment: Попробуйте Victoria из-под Windows.

Answer (score 1):

А как же Master и Slave на старых железках? Там ведь не только перемычка играет роль, но и в какой последовательности с данной перемычкой подключено устройство по шлейфу. Приходилось с таким сталкиваться в старые-добрые времена. При отсутствии перемычки хард переводится в режим Cable Select. В этом режиме устройство будет Мастером или Слэйвом в зависимости от того, как оно подключено к шлейфу – к середине или к концу шлейфа. Такой режим выбирать не советуют, иначе на контроллере может оказаться два мастера или два подчиненных устройства (если вы неправильно их подключите).
Уверен почти на 100 процентов, что проблема в этом, если вы видите диск через биос.

[Вот небольшая статья по этому поводу](http://tinklai.dkd.lt/papildomai/2_ide/2ide.htm)

Если же это прочитанная информация вам не поможет, опишите точнее что и в какой последовательности у вас подключено к конкретным шлейфам. Потому что у вас на материнской плате минимум primary и secondary каналы, на каждом из которых еще висят мастер и слейв.

Comment: Не указал, что все устройства у меня SATa из IDE только этот винт.

Comment: Значит, если стоит мастер перемычка подключите в самый дальний разъем от материнской платы на шлейфе, а не тот же, что без перемычки или снимите её вообще, для определения. НО меня терзают сомнения, что это вы уже сделали. Верно?

Comment: Ну да, я так и подключал. С перемычкой в БИОСе он определяется как Мастер, без как Слейв. Старый ВД без перемычки определяется как Мастер. Ну и оба я не подключал. Либо один либо второй. Так что оба цеплялись на конец шлейфа, каждый  в свое время.

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor не могли бы вы написать модель вашей материнской платы, меня терзают смутные сомнения по поводу второго ответа. И вы написали что линукс видит хард - через gparted не получается разметить?

Comment: Системная плата Gigabyte GA-EP43-DS3L
Описание драйвера SAMSUNG SP1203N ATA Device

Почему же, Gparted прекрасно видел его, было два раздела, информация читаема, Уже удалил с виндовса. Просто хотел прогнать его, так как есть сбойные сектора. (Понятное дело взял б\у за копейки, ценное ничего хранить не буду понятно, но так чтобы на определенное время расчистить основной винт, установить программы и т.д.)

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor у вас в биос какой режим выставлен для хардов? PATA IDE Mode или саташный? Если первое, то имеет смысл применить советы из другого ответа. Если второе, то нужно переключить контроллер в иде режим и поправить конфиги, потому что в случае выставления иде - хард, который подключен к нему автоматически станет мастером, а сам шлейф primary. возможно название настроек будет отличатся

Comment: я не совсем понял про режимы Вот так определяется у меня в БИОС http://itmages.ru/image/view/3889215/3568c14e вот такие настройки http://itmages.ru/image/view/3889214/d83aab9c А вот такое я вижу из-под MHDD http://itmages.ru/image/view/3889216/32efc68f

Answer (score 0):

Присоединюсь к ответу:
MHDD, по-умолчанию не работает с каналом Primary. Если диагностируемый HDD подключен к каналу Primary, вам сначала нужно разблокировать этот канал. Отредактируйте файл MHDD.CFG (замените значение ключа #PRIMARY_ENABLED с FALSE на TRUE. Но тестировать программой тот же HDD, на котором она физически находится недопустимо (потеряете данные).
Со Slave устройствами, в целях безопасности, mhdd тоже не работает. Но если надо, то можно сделать так: нажмите SHIFT+F3 для выбора диска. SLAVE-устройства в нём не отображаются, но их можно выбрать, выбирая чётные номера. Например, чтобы выбрать накопитель Primary Slave, необходимо выбрать устройство номер 2, соответственно, чтобы выбрать Secondary Slave, выбирайте 4. Для накопителей, подключенных к PCI-платам, номера Slave-устройств будут нечётными.

Comment: Читал. Пробовал. Не видит. Рабочий винт и диск CD с которого происходила загрузка - SATA. Винт. который хочу проверить IDE. Вот если к этому каналу подключить Samsung, программа его не видит. Если же его отключить, а подключить стары WD он без проблем определяется программой. В БИОСе и в первом и во втором случае он отображается как Master. Так как САТа у меня аж шесть, а ИДЕ идет уже после них, он далеко не Primary